# Angular 2 + MVC routing: routing fails after fallback

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-mvc-4, typescript

I'm building an Angular 2 app. 
When the project is started using Visual Studio 2017, I can successfully route to the the app inside an Area (Home2017/Start/Index.cshtml):

```
  Route toHome2017 = null;
  toHome2017 = routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Default_to_Home2017",
              url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Start", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
              namespaces: new string[] { "BIP2.Areas.Home2017.Controllers" }
            );

            toHome2017.DataTokens["area"] = "Home2017";
```

Angular routing is:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([

        {
            path: 'Architecture',
            component: ArchitectureComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },            
        {
            path: '',
            component: StartpageComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full'
        }
    ])
]
```

When I navigate to /Architecture, the Angular routing is working. 
However, when I refresh the page, and redirect it to Home2017/Start/Index using:

```
 toHome2017 = routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default_to_Architecture",
            url: "Architecture",
            defaults: new { controller = "Start", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "BIP2.Areas.Home2017.Controllers" }
          );
            toHome2017.DataTokens["area"] = "Home2017";
```

The app is loaded, **but** the Angular path: '' with the StartpageComponent is displayed with the Url /Architecture/.

What am I missing?

EDIT: The same technique was working for me in AngularJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found it out:

Running the app on localhost, setting the base ref:

```
document.write('<base href="' + document.location.href + '" />');
```

caused the base to be /Architecture when I refreshed the page. 
Changeing it to simply:

```
<base href="/" />
```

solved it.